# Update table column only if the ids don't exist in another table

Tags: mysql, join, update

I have two tables that are in play here. A users table and a users_roles table. I need to update the users status column to 0 for almost all users except for a few, we can target these users by uid perhaps? Also the users that have a uid in the users_roles table should not be affected.

**Table - users**

- Col - uid
- Col - status

**Table - users_roles**

- Col - uid
- Col - rid

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: I finally figured it out. Trick was to check if the users_roles uid column is null.       
`UPDATE users u LEFT JOIN users_roles ur ON u.uid = ur.uid SET status = 0 WHERE u.uid > 1 AND u.status <> 0 AND ur.uid is null AND u.uid <> 99;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I finally figured it out. Trick was to check if the users_roles uid column is null. `UPDATE users u LEFT JOIN users_roles ur ON u.uid = ur.uid SET status = 0 WHERE u.uid > 1 AND u.status <> 0 AND ur.uid is null AND u.uid <> 99;` – Brian N

Test

```
UPDATE users u 
SET u.status = 0 
WHERE u.uid > 1 
  AND u.uid <> 99
  AND u.status
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM users_roles ur
                   WHERE u.uid = ur.uid );
```

Its performance may be higher.

Comment: Thank you @Akina that had much better performance.

I also received a list of 16 users so I used:
`AND u.uid NOT IN ('2', '7', '8', '99', .....)` which also made it more reliable.